# Rectangle Object-Oriented Development - Equals() method

Tags: java, oop, class, equals

need some help here. Working on "Classes and Object-Oriented Development" and could use some help with both my logic and code for a question in the textbook.

**Question:** I am asked to Modify my previous example of my Rectangle class to override the equals() and toString() methods. Two rectangles are equal when they both have the same length and width.

**My approach:** I tried to change it to do this, and then decided it would be easier to compare by areas, rather than comparing both by width and length, so below is what I have so far. Let me know if you have any ideas to help. There is a previous example of the equals() method that compares a circle's radius but isnt helping when comparing 2 different things. Thanks before hand all ! If your wondering why they are all not their own separate files, I haven't gotten there in the chapter yet so it's alot to look at I know ;P

```
 /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package chapter8javaExamples;

/**
 *
 * @author Eric
 */
public class Rectangle {
    private double length, width;


/**
 * constructor
 * pre: none
 * post: A rectangle class is created. 
 */
public Rectangle() {
    length = 2;   //default length
    width = 4;    //default width
}


/**
 * constructor
 * pre: none
 * post: A rectangle object is created with length and width.
 */
public Rectangle (double l, double w) {
    length = l;
    width = w;

}


/**
 * Changes the length of the rectangle
 * pre: none
 * post: Length has been changed.
 */
public void setLength (double newLength) {
    length = newLength;
}




/**
 * Changes the width of the rectangle.
 * pre: none
 * post: Width has been changed.
 */
public void setWidth (double newWidth) {
    width = newWidth;
}


/**
 * Returns the length of the rectangle.
 * pre: none
 * post: The length of the rectangle has been returned. 
 */
public double getLength() {
    return(length);
}


/**
 * Returns the width of the rectangle.
 * pre: none
 * post: The width of the rectangle has been returned.
 */
public double getWidth() {
    return(width);
}


/**
 * Returns the area of rectangle
 * pre: none
 * post: The area of the rectangle is returned
 */
public double area() {
    double triArea;

    triArea = length * width;
    return(triArea);
}


/**
 * Returns the perimeter of the rectangle
 * pre: none
 * post: The perimeter of the rectangle is returned
 */
public double perimeter() {
    double triPer;

    triPer = length + width + length + width;
    return(triPer);
}


/**
 * Displays the formula for area of a rectangle.
 * pre: none
 * post: The formula is displayed.
 */
public static void displayAreaFormula(){
    System.out.println("The formula for the area of a rectangle is a=l*w");
}

/**
 * Determines if the object is equal to another
 * Circle object.
 * pre: c is a Circle object.
 * post: true has been returned if the objects have
 * the same radii, false otherwise.
 */
public boolean equals(Object r) {
    Rectangle testObj = (Rectangle) r;
    Rectangle testObj2 = (Rectangle) r2;

    if (testObj.getArea() == area && testObj2.getArea == area()) {
        return(true);
    } else {
        return(false);
    }
}


/**
 * Returns a String that represents the Circle object.
 * pre: none
 * post: A string representing the Circle object has
 * been returned.
 */
public String toString(){
    String rectangleString;

    rectangleString = "Rectangle has the Area " + length*width;
    return(rectangleString);
}

/**
 * 
 * @param args 
 */
    public static void main(String [] args){
    Rectangle spot = new Rectangle();
    Rectangle spot2 = new Rectangle(5, 9);

    System.out.println("Area is: " + spot.area());
    System.out.println("Perimeter: " + spot.perimeter());
    Rectangle.displayAreaFormula();
}
```

}

Comment: As per your implementation, a rectangle with dimensions (6l x 6w) is same as rectangle with dimensions (12l x 3w). Is that right?

Comment: I like your extensive documentation. Keep at it. It'll help you a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that comparing the areas is a good idea in the `equals` method, because a rectangle that is 2x8 would equal a rectangle that is 4x4, because both areas are 16.  This contradicts your requirement:

> Two rectangles are equal when they both have the same length and width.

Here, your `r2` variable is undefined.  But beyond that, the `equals` method shouldn't compare two other objects, it should compare `this` object to another object.

You should return `true` if the `r` object is a `Rectangle` and this rectangle's length matches the other rectangle's length and this rectangle's width matches the other rectangle's width.

Answer (score 2):

Your equals method should always have the following structure:

```
public boolean equals(Object r) {
    if(r == null || !r instanceof Rectangle) return false;
    // rest of the code
}
```

This is because you don't want to perform operations on a null-reference (which would throws errors), and `this` can't equals `null` anyway. Secondly: if r is not an instance of the rectangle class, we can quit before having to perform other operations, because a Rectangle would not equal a String, or a Circle.

Now, to get to your question: if you want to check on equality purely by width and length, I would write the method like this:

```
public boolean equals(Object r) {
    if(r == null || !r instanceof Rectangle) return false;
    if(length == r.length && width == w.width) return true;
    return false;
}
```

This compares the width and length. If they are both equal, two rectangles are equal. You are comparing the area, but this could give false positives. Take this example:

```
Rectangle r1;
Rectangle r2;

r1.width = 10;
r1.length = 5;

r2.width = 5;
r2.length = 10;
```

Your code would produce a positive, while these rectangles are orientated differently.

Answer (score 0):

Two rectangles are equal when they have both same length and width.

Are these following rectangles the same?

[image: 100x100]

and

[image: 200x50]

Hey! Both have the same area don't they?

So in short, no you have use `&&` to see if the length and breadth of both are equal or you could compare the `.toString()`s of both rectangles to see if they are exact.

Comment: oh and if anyone was wondering, I used placehold.it to generate the pics.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answers (read those first)

If you are comparing "physical" objects (a block of wood for example) then you might want to compare length to width and width to length as well.  The orientation a user inputs might be submitted differently for two of the same objects. Consider this when reading your requirements.